# Ionic 3 to 4 upgrade build errors in [@angular/compiler and @angular/core]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am upgrading an existing Ionic 3 application to Ionic 4. I updated dependencies in my package.json to latest versions of Angular (Angular 7+), Ionic (4+). When I build the project I get some errors related to angular compiler and angular core.

```
typescript: node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/ml_parser/ast.d.ts, line: 17 
            '=' expected. 

      L16:  type: string;
      L17:  cases: ExpansionCase[];
      L18:  sourceSpan: ParseSourceSpan;


 typescript: node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/injector.d.ts, line: 68 
            '=' expected. 

      L67:  constructor(providers: StaticProvider[], parent?: Injector, source?: string | null);
      L68:  get<T>(token: Type<T> | InjectionToken<T>, notFoundValue?: T, flags?: InjectFlags): T;
      L69:  get(token: any, notFoundValue?: any): any;


typescript: node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/definition.d.ts, line: 317 
            ';' expected. 

     L316:  * Static attributes to set on host element.
     L318:  * Even indices: attribute name
```

Here are some important dependencies (upgraded to latest) of my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "7.2.15",
        "@angular/common": "7.2.15",
        "@angular/compiler": "7.2.15",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.2.15",
        "@angular/core": "7.2.15",
        "@angular/forms": "7.2.15",
        "@angular/http": "7.2.15",
        ......
        "rxjs": "6.5.2"

},

"devDependencies" : {
   "typescript": "2.6.2",
    "webpack": "3.12.0"

}
```

I upgraded typescript to `3.1.6` and the issue still exists.
What could be the reason for these build errors ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

make backup of your project then delete your node_module folder and run

```
npm install -g
```

after download all modules 
run

```
npm audit fix
```